# MIPS32 memory implementation in java

Tags: java, memory, mips32

I want to implement MIPS32 in Java to create a simulator similar to spim. The problem I have a the moment it try to figure out how to implement memory.

```
private static Memory[] memoryArray = new Memory[1000];
```

Is how I'm implementing memory at the moment, its an array of objects containing the address it starts at and the value it contains, taking up 32 bits of memory. The problem is I need to allow for around 2gb of memory and loading this into an array is miles to slow to deal with.

[image: Memory Map]

Above shows the values I need and how It's lay out. Is there anyway to effectively implement that amount of memory into my simulator via an object array or will I need another solution.

Comment: `1000` ints is not 2^32.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes i understand that but if i do `67108863` ints it practically doesn't run anymore